# Conflictive scroll on UITableView within UIScrollView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiscrollview, uigesturerecognizer

I had three `UITableView`s contained in one `UIScrollView`(`pagingEnable = YES`),

The hierarchy looks like:

```
                                 +--visible area--+  ---+
+---------`UIScrollView`---------+---------------+|  --+|
| +-------------+ +-------------+|+-------------+||  -+||
| |      0      | |      1      |||      2      |||   |||
| |`UITableView`| |`UITableView`|||`UITableView`|||  equal height
| |             | |             |||             |||   |||
| +-------------+ +-------------+|+-------------+||  -+||
+--------------------------------+---------------+|  --+| 
                                 +----------------+  ---+
```

The **`UIScrollView`** (as container view) had it's`contentSize.height` set to fit the screen height, thus it's only **scrollable in horizontal** direction.
And each **`UITableView`** is **vertically scrollable** as is.

The problem is I have no idea which view (`ScrollView` or `TableView`) handle a current finger touch on the screen.

It works fine when I scroll a perfect vertical / horizontal path through the screen to move the `ScrollView` or `TableView`.

While if I scroll from the bottom right to the top left (like a backslash "\") it sometimes move the ScrollView horizontally, sometimes move the TableView vertically...even worse it move none of both but just shake the `TableView` ridiculously. **I just can't move what I expected**.

I assume it's because `UIScrollView` and `UITableView`'s ScrollView have detection conflict .

Here I added log to the UIScrollViewDelegate method:

```
//in each ViewController handle a UITableView

    - (void)scrollViewWillBeginDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{
            NSLog(@"TableView touched")
        }
    }

//in the ViewController handle the UIScrollView

    - (void)scrollViewWillBeginDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{
            NSLog(@"ScrollView touched")
        }
    }

//as a side note...I set three ViewControllers(each holds one TableView) into a ContainerViewController(holds ScrollView)
```

They logged out one after another randomly...but almost the same time.

Any idea would be appreciated!

Comment: Maybe you should try to only enable user interaction on a UITableView if it is centered in your UIScrollView and disable it otherwise.

Comment: Did you really type in the hierarchy?

Comment: @OutOfBounds yeah there surely would be only one UITableView in center at a time, the problem is the table scroll would bother the paging scroll.

Comment: @refdev if you mean whether I made the hierarchy by typing ... yes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a `UIPanGestureRecognizer` for the entire view. Store the initial location, and from the current location, calculate if it is a horizontal or vertical movement. (If the x coordinate is changing more, than it is horizontal, if y, vertical.)

Once the direction is clear, forward the movement to the table view or the scroll view.

Or a better solution: use a table view controller and add edge swipe gestures to switch like if they were in a tab controller.

Comment: wasn't able to handle the delay of forwarding the direction from pan gesture to move my scrollview/tableview ... end it up using pageViewController right now (there's also a scrollview in it that I can scroll in a smoother way ... wondering why).

Comment: @sharky101 can you explain in more detail how you ended up fixing your problem?